# swift wait until the urlsession finished

Tags: swift, api, uicollectionview, urlsession

each time i call this api https://foodish-api.herokuapp.com/api/ i get an image. I don't want one image, i need 11 of them, so i made the loop to get 11 images.
But what i can't do is reloading the collection view once the loop is finish.

```
func loadImages() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for _ in 1...11{
                       let url = URL(string: "https://foodish-api.herokuapp.com/api/")!
                       let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
                           guard let data = data else { return }
                           do {
                               let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : String]
                               print(json!["image"]!)
                               self.namesOfimages.append(json!["image"]!)
                               
                           } catch {
                               print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                           }
                           }.resume()
        }
    }
    self.collectionV.reloadData()
    print("after resume")
}
```

Comment: It depends. Do you want to refresh this 11 times, as each finishes? Or once when all 11 are finished. If the former, put it right after the update of `namesOfimages`, as ahem advised. If the latter, use a dispatch group, calling `enter` before each request, calling `leave` in the completion handler, and then add a `notify` block that will reload the table. This is has been outlined many times, so if this pattern isn't familiar, you'll find many S.O. answers on this topic.

Comment: Some unrelated observations: 1. The outer `DispatchQueue.main.async` is redundant given that `dataTask` is already asynchronous. 2. Where you _do_ need this async dispatch to the main thread is the update of `namesOfimages`.  You are currently updating this from the `URLSession` background queue, introducing a data race. You don't want to update model properties from background threads without some synchronization (or just doing it from the main thread, the simplest way to synchronize).

Comment: 3. If doing 11 network requests, you can probably get away with blithely launching all 11 at the same time, like the above, but if ever initiating a lot more than that, you will probably want to constrain the number of concurrent requests that you will start at any given moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when we want to know when a series of concurrent tasks (such as these network requests) are done, we would reach for a `DispatchGroup`. Call `enter` before the network request, call `leave` in the completion handler, and specify a `notify` block, e.g.

```swift
/// Load images
///
/// - Parameter completion: Completion handler to return array of URLs. Called on main queue

func loadImages(completion: @escaping ([URL]) -> Void) {
    var imageURLs: [Int: URL] = [:]   // note, storing results in local variable, avoiding need to synchronize with property
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let count = 11

    for index in 0..<count {
        let url = URL(string: "https://foodish-api.herokuapp.com/api/")!
        group.enter()
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            defer { group.leave() }

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let foodImage = try JSONDecoder().decode(FoodImage.self, from: data)
                imageURLs[index] = foodImage.url
            } catch {
                print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        let sortedURLs = (0..<count).compactMap { imageURLs[$0] }
        completion(sortedURLs)
    }
}
```

Personally, rather than `JSONSerialization`, I use `JSONDecoder` with a `Decodable` type to parse the JSON response. (Also, I find the key name, `image`, to be a bit misleading, so I renamed it to `url` to avoid confusion, to make it clear it is a URL for the image, not the image itself.) Thus:

```swift
struct FoodImage: Decodable {
    let url: URL

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case url = "image"
    }
}
```

Also note that the above is not updating properties or reloading the collection view. A routine that is performing network requests should not also be updating the model or the UI. I would leave this in the hands of the caller, e.g.,

```swift
var imageURLs: [URL]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // caller will update model and UI

    loadImages { [weak self] imageURLs in
        self?.imageURLs = imageURLs
        self?.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Note:

1. The `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not necessary. These requests already run asynchronously.
2. Store the temporary results in a local variable. (And because `URLSession` uses a serial queue, we do not have to worry about further synchronization.)
3. The dispatch group `notify` block, though, uses the `.main` queue, so that the caller can conveniently update properties and UI directly.
4. Probably obvious, but I am parsing the `URL` directly, rather than parsing a string and converting that to a `URL`.
5. When fetching results concurrently, you have no assurances regarding the order in which they will complete. So, one will often capture the results in some order-independent structure (such as a dictionary) and then sort the results before passing it back.

   In this particular case, the order doesn't strictly matter, but I included this sort-before-return pattern in my above example, as it is generally the desired behavior.

Anyway, that yields:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get one reload after finish loading of all 11 images you need to use DispatchGroup. Add a property that create a group:

```
private let group = DispatchGroup()
```

Then modify your loadImages() function:

```
func loadImages() {
    for _ in 1...11 {
        let url = URL(string: "https://foodish-api.herokuapp.com/api/")!
        group.enter()
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.group.leave()
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : String]
                print(json!["image"]!)
                self.namesOfimages.append(json!["image"]!)
            } catch {
                print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
        self?.collectionV.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Some description:

1. On the method call group.enter() will be called 11 times
2. On each completion of image downloading group.leave() will be called
3. When group.leave() will be called the same count like group.enter() group make call of the block that you defined in group.notify()

More about [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)

Notice that you need handle create and store different DispatchGroup object if you need to download different groups of images in the same time.